# need guidance in php ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need guidance in PHP Ajax.

I want to develop feature something like Gmail.

Now here we go.

I have two page one is login and second is display.

Once login user will redirect to display page where he can see messages send from other user.

Now I want to implement ajax like whenever user send message to other user then other user immediately notify that he/she got message and also need to append it to their mail box.

I know I can do it using `setInterval` but is there other way because `setInterval` might be for either `5 sec` or `10 sec` but I want to fire it whenever other user send him message.

I see this in [zaarly.com](http://www.zaarly.com) and Gmail form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Well i want to build feature something like gmail." --- haha. With such questions you won't do anything even far from that

Comment: setInterval is an option but it could be quite heavy on the server if you had lots of people using this. How would you be storing your messages? You could look into using JSON files.

Comment: @sam yah i m using json and load is not a issue now i want to notify user instantaneously whenever he got response with response append to messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is a browser-side technology. It doesn't have the ability to receive messages from the server without the browser asking for them. If you want to use Ajax for this, then you need to have it ping the server regularly using a solution along the lines of the one you suggested using `setTimeout` or similar.

In fact Ajax is the wrong term for this sort of thing. The term you need to search for is actually known as **Comet**. You can read more about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29.

Comet is a catch-all term for server-push-to-the-browser technology. Your solution is one of many possible implementations for Comet, although it isn't particularly efficient in terms of bandwidth. The wiki page linked above lists a number of other possible ways of achieving your goal, which you may want to investigate. But googling for 'Comet' rather than 'Ajax' will definitely help your research here.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to build 'something like gmail' you're going to need a lot of research into the following and some javascript skills. Its the only language you'll be using.

- Node.js - A backend server that can use sockets to deliver real time
  updates to the browser.
- Backbone.js - A semi structured way of building single page
  applications "like gmail"

I'd also include Require.js to that list which is basically used to load all the Backbone javascript files asynchronously. It helps to keep the file structure of your application maintainable.

Comment: not exact as gmail i just gave example that they have this instantaneous response feature. so does node and backbone is compatible with jQuery.?

Comment: You won't really need jQuery on node since there is not need for DOM manipulation on the server side but backbone fully supports it. Its practically needed.

Comment: What I outlined in my answer requires some time to get use to but if you really want to build a robust application without having to worry too much about scalability issues, its probably the most 'future proof' way to go. Check out http://socket.io/ for more information. It basically allows you to send messages from the server to the browser in real time. If its an old browser then it will fallback to polling, which is similar to Comet mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I note you state in a comment "instantaneous response feature". You should take a look at long polling [(push technology)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology), understand it, then choose the right language, technologies and architecture to fit the job.

> In a web/AJAX context, long polling is also known as **Comet programming**.

Also "PHP AJAX" - PHP is server side, JavaScript is client side. Don't confuse them or you'll be screwed :)